# Sending a firebase dynamic link over SMS from the desktop page

Tags: firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I have firebase deep links working in my app, and when a user visits them on desktop it takes them to a custom webpage I made that says "This content is only available on the app.  Please download it to continue" with app store links for my app.

I want to add a form that says "enter your phone number to get texted the link to download the app" and I have no issues doing that with twilio.

Where I'm stuck is that I want to SMS the original deep link to the user.  But the firebase deep link system already redirected me to the desktop page so I don't have access to the deep link anymore.  Is there any way to get the original deep link?

I do have the path of the original deep link in the URL so I could possibly reconstruct it?  But is there an easier way, or an existing solution to my problem of wanting to get users to install our app without losing the deep link context?

Answer (score 0):

If you create your originally link manually you can use the Other Platform Parameters `ofl` to send a parameter of the dynamic link to be sent in text message to the desktop users.
See the [doc's](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually) on how to manually create your link.

Alternatively, in the past I've added a parameter to the short link which has been passed through to the webapp, maybe you could use that to pass the dynamic link. Not tested, but should have the desired effect.